# RabbitMQ + Nginx with mTLS setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ service running on an AWS EC2 instance. Currently it's set up to connect via mTLS on port 5671.

But I want to secure it my not opening port 5671 on my server and instead forward it via a reverse proxy, namely Nginx.

How do I set it up so that I have a Nginx forwarding connections to RabbitMQ but with mTLS?
If Nginx is used, does it mean Nginx will accept the mTLS connection and terminate then forward the connection to RabbitMQ without TLS?